# Reset Android notification count

Tags: android, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

`setNumber` is only incremented value

We can change notification count by using `setNumber` ([docs](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/notifications/badges#set-custom-count)). But it's only incrementing counter. On each call `setNumber(10)` notification counter incremented by 10 every time. So on first push notification it will be 10 then 20 and etc. Is there any way to reset/decrease or maybe provide current value updating old one in counter?